# EF SaveChanges() throws an exception 'The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null'

Tags: entity-framework

I have been reading all similar posts I found regarding EF but I can't still manage to found a solution.

I'm very new to the EF and I have been reading some useful info about working with it but I think that I'm missing something.

The scenario is like this:

I want a user to be able to create an account in an ASP.NET webpage. So I have a table named 'Accounts'. The user must agree with the condition terms of the site, that may be updated in the futere, so I have also a table called 'ConditionTerms' that has 1 to many relation with the account (many accounts have an unique condition term).

I wanted to separete the specific personal user data from the data of the account so I also created a table called 'Persons' and I set the relation ship so that a person may have many accounts.

Now, when I want to save an account into the database, I retrieve the last conditionTerm available in the database and I attach it to the account entity. Then when I try to save the data via SaveChanges() I get the exception mentioned in the title of the post. The thing is that if all entities are new, when the associations are created, the EntityState for all the items is 'Detached' and it works, but when I retrieve the existing conditionTerm from the data base and I add it to the account.ConditionTerm, the account changes its state to 'Added' and then it throws the exception.

I read somewhere that when this happens, it means that all the entity tree is considered as already added by the context and I should only need to call SaveChanges() without the AddObject() method since it is already added. I tried this and then I get no exception and the code ends, but then if I check the database (SQL Server 2008 express) the account hasn't been added at all.

This is the code I'm trying and I think it should work but it's clear that I'm missing something:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCreateNewAccount()
{
    try
    {
        AccountRepository accountRepository = new AccountRepository();

        Account account = new Account()
        {
            Username = "TestUsername",
            Password = "TestPassword",
            Email = "TestEmail",
            Nickname = "TestNickName",
            Quote = "Test Quote",
            AgreedToTermsDate = DateTime.Now,
            CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
            LastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now
        };

        // This works (all new entities!)
        //ConditionTerm conditionTerm = new ConditionTerm()
        //{
        //    Text = "This is some test condition term.",
        //    CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
        //    LastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now
        //};

        //This does not work (attaching an existing entity to a new one)
        ConditionTerm conditionTerm = new ConditionTermsRepository().GetCurrentTerm();

        Person person = new Person()
        {
            FirstName = "TestName",
            Surname = "TestSurname",
            CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
            LastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now
        };

        account.ConditionTerm = conditionTerm;
        account.Person = person;   

        using (ImproveEntities entities = Connection.GetModel())
        {
            if (account.ID > 0)
            {
                Account newAccount = new Account();
                newAccount.ID = account.ID;
                entities.Accounts.Attach(newAccount);
                entities.Accounts.ApplyCurrentValues(account);
            }

            else
            {
                entities.Accounts.AddObject(account);
                entities.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception)
    { 
    }
}
```

Any help would be very much apreciated!

**EDIT:** This is the GetCurrentTerm() method:

```
    public ConditionTerm GetCurrentTerm()
    {
        using (ImproveEntities entities = Connection.GetModel())
        {
            ConditionTerm conditionTerm = (from ct in entities.ConditionTerms
                                           orderby ct.CreationDate descending
                                           select ct).FirstOrDefault();
            return conditionTerm;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are working with 2 contexts there, right? I guess that `GetCurrentTerm` uses its own context and the `using` creates a second context. Is the context in `GetCurrentTerm` disposed or is the `conditionTerm` still attached to this context? Can you show the code of `GetCurrentTerm`? And are we only talking about the `else` block? I cannot see when `account.ID` could be greater than 0 in your code (unless your Account constructor sets the ID to some value).

Comment: Hi Slauma! I added the code for the GetCurrentTerm() method. I read somewhere that it was the typical best practice to use the context within a using clause so it always get disposed in the end. Is there anything wrong with that? The else block doesn't make much sense here in the test method but it is suposed to go in a SaveAccount() method where I can pass either a new account or one that already exists (so I can update it).

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `if` block. For the moment I'm trying to add a new account, then I'll get into more detail with the update.

Comment: I've tried an answer for your case to create a new account.

Comment: The `using` block is fine. But having a separate context in every repository or even every method of a repository can be problematic. It's often easier and more the "standard practice" to create one single context for a bigger DB operation and then inject this context (in constructor or in every method) into the repositories. In your specific case you would not need to manually attach the `ConditionTerm` to the context because it is already loaded by the query which happens in the same context then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to insert a new account along with a new user into the database. But you don't want to create a new `ConditionTerm` but instead assign an existing `ConditionTerm` to the account.

The problem is that you fetch the existing `ConditionTerm` in another context (in your `GetCurrentTerm`) than the context you use for saving the new account. This second context doesn't know anything about the `ConditionTerm`, so you must EF explicitely tell that this conditionTerm already exists by attaching it to the second context:

```
    // ...
    using (ImproveEntities entities = Connection.GetModel())
    {
        entities.ConditionTerms.Attach(conditionTerm);

        account.ConditionTerm = conditionTerm;
        account.Person = person;   

        entities.Accounts.AddObject(account);
        entities.SaveChanges();
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution worked like a charm, very good explanation also. You saved may day. Now I understand a little bit more how the EF works although I find it a little bit weird (couldn't the context work like a singleton? silly question maybe)

Comment: I would mark your answer as useful but I'm quite new here and I don't have enough reputation, I'm sorry!

Comment: @Albert C.: Just found an old answer about injecting a single context into the repos: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823115/adding-user-to-a-role-inserts-a-duplicate-user-into-users-table/5823230#5823230. A singleton would work in your specific situation, yes. But generally working with a singleton context which lives during the whole application lifetime is widely considered as the pure evil and can cause a lot of trouble, especially because objects do not disappear from the context after `SaveChanges`, the context is only cleared when you dispose it (but then it's no singleton anymore).