# Entity Framework 5.0 Conventions

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5, c#-5.0

I am just beginning to learn Entity Framework (starting with 5.0) and running into some issues. After watching a few videos on Pluralsight, I decided to get creative and created an abstract base class that inherited from DbContext and exposed a single "DataContext" property that was a DbSet of a generic type. Something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseDataContext<E> : DbContext
     where E : CustomEntity
{
      public DbSet<E> DataContext {get;set;}

      public BaseDataContext()
      {
           Database.SetInitializer<BaseDataContext<E>>(null);
      }
 }
```

This seemed to be working great until I started dealing with entities that had relationships with each other (parent/child). What was occurring is when I tried to add a new child entity to the database via a data class that inherited BaseDataContext is instead of just attaching the reference (meaning, taking the child and say "your parent key is 123"), it created another record with a new key for the parent and all other fields duplicated and made this new record the parent of the child. I tried just setting the key property of my child (nulling out the property that was exposed with the data), but that didn't change anything. I found a thread on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823115/adding-user-to-a-role-inserts-a-duplicate-user-into-users-table)) that said it wasn't a good idea to do multiple data contexts like what I was attempting to do and seemed to explain exactly what was happening.

My question for this is, with the popularity EF seems to be gaining for everyone, is this the common approach? To create a single data context that is then passed around with constructors everywhere? Or is there a simpler way that is more common? This would especially apply if things get into background threads since passing a context there might get difficult.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, that doesn't inherit from anything.

Comment: That's what I get for writing this so late - fixed!

Comment: What is the idea behind this base class? Can you give an example of how you use a derived type? If you have one context type per entity type... yes, _that's_ unconventional.

Comment: My intention was to have a data class per entity type (like you would've done before EF/L2S) and that would inherit from this base context which provided DB access. The top-level classes would've all implemented their associated interfaces (this is a WCF backend) which exposed the various CRUD methods (and so on) that each data class required based on its entity type. Hopefully that makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the most out of EF, as any tool, when you use as intended. So it's good you ask. Entity Framework, especially code-first, is all about persistence ignorance (explained [here for example](http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/archive/2010/01/09/a-look-at-persistence-ignorance-in-entity-framework-4-via.aspx)). I don't know what your comment "like you would've done before EF/L2S" refers to, but it sounds like [active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html). That's not the way to go.

The context is responsible for materializing entities from the store, tracking changes and saving changes to the database. In more detail: the context manages the unit of work (tracking changes) and it's `DbSet` members serve as basic repositories (materializing and saving). The entity classes themselves know nothing about this. (As a side note: in the `ObjectContext` API they do, but they can be coded against as persistence ignorant).

Now about "multiple contexts". The question you refer to is about multiple context *instances* of the same context *type*. Your question is about multiple context *types* (and, necessarily, multiple instances). Let's sort this out:

- **Number of context types:** It is common to have a very limited number of context types, often even just one. Why? Because a context covering a large part of the database is able to retrieve and persist many different object graphs. So it serves a large number of use cases, present and future, stable and changing, but it is stable itself. It only changes when the database changes, not when the application changes. (I should say though that there are advocates of one context type per use case, but I've found it to be inevitable that they have a large number of classes in common, very confusing).
- **Number of context instances:** this issue cannot be fully covered in a few words, but it should be kept in mind that a context (1) caches data and (2) tracks and stores changes. So long-lived contexts soon contain stale data and they grow in size as changes occur. The consensus is to keep contexts "short" lived, but what is short? It could be one instance per http request, one per service call, one per (business) transaction, but also one per form in an MDI interface, one per thread... See a useful discussion on Linq-to-Sql contexts [here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Feb/05/Linq-to-SQL-DataContext-Lifetime-Management), the same goes for EF contexts (or NHibernate sessions for that matter). One thing is clear: don't use one static context, as some people are tempted to do.

So be as creative as you can, experiment as much as you can. Use EF as it is intended to and have lots of fun!

Comment: I think that clears it up for me. I was trying to have a context per entity type (combined with generics) because prior to EF/L2S I used to do individual data classes (with generics/inheritance) so I could share based functionality across the board. I think what I'm seeing here is similar to L2S in that I should only have one true "context" class (with DbSet entries per entity type) that is the end-all database access point, and then my individual data classes call that context, instead of having independent contexts that don't know about each other. Thanks for the help!